# Unable to position view exactly in the middle of the screen using absolute layout

Tags: android

I am trying to position a view in the middle of the screen using absolute layout.

First, I get the screen height in pixels

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int height_px = size.y;
```

Second, I convert the screen height into density pixels

```
    Resources resources = this.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float height_dp = height_px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
```

Then I print out of the value of the screen height in density pixels for testing

```
    Log.v("TAG height: ", String.valueOf(height_dp));  // prints 640
```

And finally, I set the y-offset of the second view `purple_view` to half of 640 (320).

```
<AbsoluteLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/white_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFF0"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/purple_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0FF0"
        android:layout_y="320dp"
        />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

However, `purple_view` view is not positioned exactly in the middle of the screen.

[image]

Comment: @ the_prole : `AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated one..Please use other layout..!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky It is the only way I know of positioning a view outside of the screen

Comment: What do you mean with *outside of the screen* ? Why don't you simply use center gravity?

Comment: I need the second view off screen, so I can animate it onto screen

Comment: `Display display` is a WHOLE display (with the status bar and action bar)

Comment: @pskink Thanks. Any way to exclude the status and action bar without taking a long route?

Comment: display = status_bar + action_bar + absolute_layout, so you can calculate what is display - status_bar - action_bar

Comment: @pskink Okay thanks, that is what I ended up doing...

Comment: `Absolute layouts are less flexible and harder to maintain than other types of layouts without absolute positioning.` Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html

Comment: @FrankN.Stein What other types of layouts have absolute positioning?

Comment: The point is: `don't use absolute positioning`. If your goal is to position something in the middle of the screen, then RelativeLayout offers you `android:centerInParent="true"`. Or its equivalent in Java (if you are really motivated to mess up with drawing your UI in code).

Comment: @Frank I don't have any alternative. I need to the view off screen so I can animate it onto screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it might help :

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(30, 40);
params.leftMargin = 50;
params.topMargin = 60;

rl.addView(iv, params);
```

Change values as u require.

Comment: The solution was to add half the height of the status and action bar